# AS3 FileReference.save doesn't work in IE11

Tags: actionscript-3, internet-explorer, flash

I'm just trying to save a simple text file with the following code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode)){
        case 'l':
            var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
                fileRef.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, function (event:Event):void { trace("File save cancelled."); });
                fileRef.save(_logger.log + (_playbackConnectionQueue ? _playbackConnectionQueue.log : '') + _recorderConnectionQueue.log, 'Log_' + (new Date()).getTime() + '.txt');
            break;
    }
});
```

The user presses the 'L' key and the save file prompt is shown for them to decide where to save. This works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE11 the CANCEL event is fired and no dialog box is shown. Is there some security setting I need to change?

Comment: Try your code with a flash player debug version for IE which you can download from [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), maybe it's firing an error.

Comment: i have the debugger and all im getting in Flash Builder is that cancel event being fired.

Comment: garbage collection occurs on your filrereference. Make it a member variable.

Comment: making it a member variable doesn't do it. ie still just does nothing.